# MIPS multu overflow

Tags: mips, qtspim

As part of a hex to decimal program I'm writing in MIPS using QT spim I load the value of 16^7 (268435456) into a generic register. I then multiply this number by 1-15 depending on the character, add the result to a running total, and divide 16^7 by 16.

However, I encounter what I assume to be overflow issues when multiplying 268435456. For instance, the code

```
    li $t0, 10
    li $t1, 268435456
    multu $t0, $t1
    mflo $t2
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Which is intended to multiply 268435456 by 10 and store the result in $t2 stores -1610612736 instead of 2684354560. Any ideas on how to fix this code to store the correct value?

Answer (score 1):

`multu` is the `unsigned` version of `mult`, which means that it is not going to generate an `overflow` because the result is taken as an unsigned number. When you show the value through a `syscall` it is taken as a `signed` number, so the signed value is shown (which in this case is negative).

You didn't give much info regarding what you are trying to achieve, but if you mean to perform a signed multiplication (meaning you want to keep the sign of the result) and store the result in a 32 bit register then you are going to run into limitations. If this is the case you will need to check whether the operation is possible within these bounds before printing the results, meaning you have to check whether the overflow happened:

```
 li $t0, 10
 li $t1, 268435456
 multu $t0, $t1
 mflo $t2
 li $t3, 31
 srl $t0, $t0, $t3
 srl $t1, $t1, $t3
 srl $t2, $t2, $t3
 xor $t0, $t0, $t1
 xor $t0, $t0, $t2
 bgtz $t0, noOperationRoutine
 li $v0, 10
 syscall 



 noOperationRoutine:
 ....
```

The above solution performs a check on the leftmost bit (obtained by shifting right by 31 bits), which is indicative of the sign (1 for negative and 0 for positive). If one and only one of the operands is negative, then the result should be negative. If both are negative or positive, then the result should be positive. I think you can see how the two xors perform this check.

If you want to work with results that are bigger than the maximum size of a signed number then you have to keep in mind that `mult` stores the low part of the result in `LO` and the high part in `HI`. At this point you are going to deal with 64 bits numbers, which occupy two words/registers each.